# Prove $\bigcup _{j=1}^nA_j \subseteq \bigcup_{j = 1}^n B_j$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Prove using induction that if $A_1, A_2,...,A_n,$ and $B_1, B_2,...,B_n$ are sets such that $A_j \subseteq B_j$ for $j = 1, 2,..., n$ then, 
$\bigcup _{j=1}^nA_j \subseteq \bigcup_{j = 1}^n B_j$

I have this so, far... I don't understand why this isn't a tautology. If $A_1 \subseteq B_1 \rightarrow \bigcup _{j=1}^nA_j \subseteq \bigcup_{j = 1}^n B_j$ is a tautology.

Please help me, and try to explain this like I'm 5. We had one example in the textbok that wasn't helpful at all.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To complete the proof, let $x\in \cup_1^{k+1} A_j$. Then $x\in A_j$ for some $j$, so $x\in \cup_1^k A_j$ or $x\in A_{k+1}$. Hence $x\in \cup_1^k B_j$ or $x\in B_{k+1}$, so $x\in \cup_1^{k+1} B_j$.

Comment: Oh thanks! The example we had was about intersections and I couldn't generalize it to unions. I felt like the disjunction was needed but then I didn't see how to infer that x must be in U k + 1 B_j

Answer (score 1):

First do the case $n=2$, then write the union of $k+1$ sets as a union of two sets, one of which is a union of $k$ sets.